# Распарсить JSON

Tags: json, php, javascript

Передаю с пыхи два массива

```
 echo json_encode($arr_right_answer);
 echo json_encode($arr_wrong_answer);
```

на Js соответвенно принимаю

```
data=$.parseJSON($.trim(data));
```

прошу подсказать как их распарсить и различить на выходе 1 от другого, по разному пытался, что то не дотумкаю

Comment: полезно использовать форматтеры и валидаторы для JSON 

вот пример:

[http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/][1]


  [1]: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Огромное Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Неправильно передаете...

```
$res = array('first'=> $arr_right_answer, 'second'=> $arr_wrong_answer));
echo json_encode($res);
```

тот JSON который вы пытаетесь передать, не является валидным