# Как распарсить JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

У меня есть [json](http://w-0rld.ru/?m=JSON) вида:

```
{"2":{"title":"1","content":"2"}}{"1":{"title":"\u041e\u0431\u043d\u043e\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0441\u0430\u0439\u0442\u0430.","content":"\u041d\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0439 \u0434\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0439\u043d \u0438 \u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f "}}
```

Как мне его распарсить и бросить в цикл, в котором все новости (это новости в json) запихнуть в блок под id "container" в виде:

```
`<div id='title'>Название новости из json</div>` 
    <div id='content'>Содержание новости из json</div>
```

Это новости вот [сюда](http://w-0rld.ru/).

Comment: У вас исходный json невалидный, для начала надо его привести к стандарту (проверить можно например на http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Для этого нужна функция JSON.parse()

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас именно такая ситуация. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/305274/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json

Answer (score 2):

Как уже заметили в комментариях, json не валидный. Валидным он будет в таком виде

```
{"2":{"title":"1","content":"2"},"1":{"title":"\u041e\u0431\u043d\u043e\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0441\u0430\u0439\u0442\u0430.","content":"\u041d\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0439 \u0434\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0439\u043d \u0438 \u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f "}}
```

Для того, что бы вывести этот json в цикле, нужно применить примерно такой код

```css
.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Тут получаем json
  var data = '{"2":{"title":"1","content":"2"},"1":{"title":"\u041e\u0431\u043d\u043e\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0441\u0430\u0439\u0442\u0430.","content":"\u041d\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0439 \u0434\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0439\u043d \u0438 \u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f "}}';
  var dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  for (var k in dataObject) {
    container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="title">'+dataObject[k].title+'</div><div class="content">'+dataObject[k].content+'</div>');
  }
</script>
```

Несмотря на то, что Вы просите сделать несколько элементов с одинаковым ID, я привел пример с class вместо id, потому что не должно быть в одном html документе несколько одинаковых id.

Comment: Как его сделать валидным? Вот мой код PHP: http://w-0rld.ru/storage/1.txt

Comment: Выводить данные с помощью json_encode. Для всего набора данных эту функцию использовать нужно только один раз. Весь набор данных должен быть одним массивом или объектом. Ваш код недоступен. 404